# Running two versions of Citrix Receiver in parallel

Tags: citrix, citrix-receiver

We deploy our software at client sites using Citrix, and install the Citrix Receiver on the client PCs.

We often find that the Citrix Receiver is already installed as part of the desktop software package at institutional clients. This is used to deploy other software and is tested and approved by the client.

Often the already installed version is older than the one that we normally use. It usually still works with our software, but tends to be slow to start or unreliable - I'm not sure if this is expected behaviour, but it is what we observe. I can replicate this by installing older versions on test PCs.

There is not the option to upgrade the pre-installed version. The environment is either Windows XP or Windows 7.

Ideally I would like to be able to run two versions of the Citrix Receiver side by side - the pre-installed older version, and our newer version. They should not impact each other. This is possible with many other pieces of software.

Does anyone know if this is possible and how I would go about it?

Comment: It might be possible to install the application to a different installation directory.  The problem you will run into is that Citrix Receiver is unlikely written to support two installations.  Its not clear why installing two different versions is possible but its not possible to upgrade the existing installation.  In either case you are changing the client's pc configuration.

Comment: I'm free to install new software, but I can't touch existing software. It's a pretty common place situation at big institutions.

Comment: I have worked and work in big institutions.  I have never heard of being able to install software on a company.  As I indicated this would be entirely be based on the fact if the second installation didn't conflict with the original installation ( it likely would ).  Before we go down that road, I am more then familar with Citrix Receiver, just have not ever thought to install 2 different versions of it on the same pc.

Comment: So under that regime, no additional software whatsoever can be installed?

Comment: In the past the non-administrator users were unable to install any software on their workstation.  The configuration was handle by the IT Department.  I currently work in an organization that personal electronic devices are not allowed to be connected to the workstations.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to pack the second citrix receiver sw in App-v. We did that more than a few years ago as we used an old citrix 4.0 farm with the most possible new version of citrix pnagent and already had this new farm with the most sofisticated agent. That worked fine for the time we needed it. In fact you can install more than 2, as long as they are packed and virtually not seeing each other. I guess that works fine with receiver.